# Extracting call graphs for external calls for node.js

Tags: javascript, dependencies, function-call, call-graph

I want to ask is there any tools that can extract call graphs for external function calls?

Here is an example:

```
var semver = require('semver')
function compare_versions(version1, version2){
    res = semver.compare(version1, version2)
    return res
}
console.log(compare_versions('1.0.1', '1.0.2'))
```

In this case, `semver` is introduced and `semver.compare()` is called in `function compare_versions`.
Is there any call graph tools that can capture such function calls?